# Django template pass array to input field

Tags: python, django

I have a hidden input field in my django template where I'm passing as value an array.

```
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'flights:flight-selection' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" id="fa_f_ids" name="fa_f_ids" value="{{ value.fa_f_ids }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Select</button>
  </form>
```

When I submit this form via post request I want to get the value of `fa_f_ids` as an array but I am getting a string instead when I'd like to get an array.

```
request.POST.get("fa_flight_id")
#=> <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['UoYqbTUlNxTEJW5AUEfgsgsLuG63dUsvX88DkwGLUJfbnwJdvcfsFhi75yie5uMX'], 'fa_f_ids': ["['AMX401-1560750900-schedule-0000', 'AMX19-1560782100-schedule-0001']"]}>
```

Comment: I had the same problem when I was getting the data from the request. I've searched a lot about this and the only solution that worked out for me was converting the querydict into a python dict and extracting the array from the value.

Comment: you can use request.POST.getlist, to change string into array

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work. `.getlist` returns this: `["['AMX401-1560750900-schedule-0000', 'AMX19-1560782100-schedule-0001']"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the array into several hidden fields, each representing one position of your array:

```py
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'flights:flight-selection' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for val in value.fa_f_ids %}
        <input type="hidden" name="fa_f_ids[{{ forloop.counter0 }}]" value="{{ val }}">
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Select</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: How do I retrieve the values in the view? `fa_f_ids[0]': ['AMX401-1560750900-schedule-0000'], 'fa_f_ids[1]': ['AMX19-1560782100-schedule-0001']}`